# jQuery Infinite Scroll Load Before Bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, scrolltop, infinite

I am using the below code for infinite scroll. It works perfectly, but only when I am at the very bottom of the page. I want it to load the next page of content when I am around 3/4 down the page.

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
            $('#infinite-load').click();
        }
});
```

I changed the code to this:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
            if($(window).scrollTop() <= ($(document).height()) - $(window).height() - 10) {
            $('#infinite-load').click();
        }
});
```

And now, on the very first scroll, no matter how little I scroll down, the next page's content loads. Scrolling a pixel once more will cause yet anther page to load.

Comment: try this instead: if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() > ($(document).height()/4*3)) {

Comment: Your code seems to have worked! Thank you so much prizm1!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to this.
Not sure if it'd work..

```
var h = ($(window).height()*1.25)+$(window).scrollTop();
h = parseInt(h);
var h2 = parseInt($(window).height()*1.25);
if(h >= ($(document).height()) && h <= ($(document).height())+h2)
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Unfortunately, the code did not work properly, but your answer would definitely be a correct solution if the structure of my site's code was proper, too. I am sure the issue of your code not working is a fault on my end.